# How can I perform Disk Cleanup on all user accounts that exist on a computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-registry, maintenance, disk-cleanup

Can you help me with some ideas regarding a possible way that I can use for performing maintenance tasks on all computer users in one shot (e.g. Disk Cleanup, Registry Cleanup)? I would like to kill all birds with one stone when I handle a certain computer.